# looping through a div with an id using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery

i am echoing data from database using while loop in php containing a button with 'button' id and a div with 'password' id as follows:

```
$q = "select title,image,password from album";
$res = mysql_query($q);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 echo "
    <table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='10'>
    <tr>
    <td><img src='uploaded/titleimages/$r[1]' height='70px' width='70px'></td>
    <td>$r[0]</br></br>
    <input type='button' name='button' value='View Album' id='button'>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
    <td>
    <div id='password'>
    <form action='album.php' method='post'> 
    Password:
    <input type='password' name='password' size='25'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
}
```

now the div with id 'password' is visible on clicking the button using the jquery below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#password").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that suppose there are 3 rows in the database,then the content inside while loop executes 3 times but the jquery code works only for the content of the 1st row.i.e.on clicking the button the div appears only for the first row content.Using class instead of id makes it work for all.in short even if using id,how to have a seperate identity for each element to individually modify them without changing other?

Any help?

Comment: **mysql_*** functions are depreceated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique... so use a class attribute to group similar elements.

So instead `button` and `password` use classes like

```
<input type='button' name='button' value='View Album' class='button'></td>
<div class='password'>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find(".password").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the id's to classes (ID's have to be unique).

Also change your jquery to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
$(this).parents('table').find(".password").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Use some counter and attach it to make an id.

For example

```
$counter = 0;
// Your while loop

while(condition){

   // form class like this => class='password-{$counter}' instead of id='password'

   $counter++;
}
```

In this way you will have a separate identity for each of the element i.e. id's will be like this:

```
password-0
password-1
password-2
...
```

After that you may use jquery loop to iterate over the elements and perform any kind of task

Comment: but using this i would have to add jquery code for each seperate id isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I certainly recommend you to use **PDO** or **MySQLi**.

- Add class as **password** and id as a unique number for each div.
- Add class for button as **button** and id as the unique number we
  gave to the div

Here is the code with the above conditions :

```
$q="select title,image,password from album";
$num=0;
$res=mysql_query($q);
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 $num++;
 echo "
<table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='10'>
<tr>
<td><img src='uploaded/titleimages/$r[1]' height='70px' width='70px'></td>
<td>$r[0]</br></br>
<input type='button' name='button' value='View Album' class='button' id='".$num."'></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
<div class='password' id='".$num."'>
<form action='album.php' method='post'> 
Password:
<input type='password' name='password' size='25'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

and the **jQuery** code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").click(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  $(".password#"+id).slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `classes` to your `button` and `div` elements,

`Input=button-image` and `Div=password-image` like,

```
<?php

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='10'>
        <tr>
            <td><img src='uploaded/titleimages/$r[1]' height='70px' width='70px'></td>
            <td>$r[0]</br></br>
            <input type='button' name='button' value='View Album' class='button-image'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div class='password-image'>
                    <form action='album.php' method='post'> 
                        Password:
                        <input type='password' name='password' size='25'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}
?>
```

And in **Javascript** use these `classes` like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-image").click(function(){
        $("div.password-image").slideUp("fast");// first slide up other open password divs
        $(this).closest('table').find("div.password-image").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you
In php, do somethinbg like this... put the id of the result in the hidden field and also to id.

```
$i=0;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<input type='button' id='button'".$i." value='something'>";
$i++;
echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden_id' value='".$i."'>";
}
```

see, in the hidden value it will give the count 
Now, call with hidden value to jquery

```
<script>
var count = $("#hidden_id").value();
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
$("#button"+i).click(function(){
$("#password").slideToggle("slow");
});
}

</script>
```

Use something like this.. Hope,this will help you.

Comment: Shouldn't **$i++;** be outside the quotes ?